# List/inspect the instance variables (self.xxx) while using pudb

Tags: python, debugging, pudb

I am trying to debug a python application using [pudb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pudb), everything is fine and good except that it's not displaying the **instance variables** (which we access with `self.xxx`). It just displays 1 variable called `self`. And it's of the original class type.

[image: Screenshot]

Even if I tell it to show after calling `str(self)`, it still only displays the object information.

[image: Screenshot2]

If you see the code has created many variables like `self.parser`, `self.groups` and I am **not** able to view/inspect any of them.

Is there a way to view all the `instance variables` of the current class while debugging using **pudb**?

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behaviour, and has nothing to do with your debugger: you only have one name, `self`.

To see its contents you can use `dir(self)`.

Comment: The question is more about how to view it in pudb debugger. Not the behavior of python itself.

Answer (score 0):

See [inspect complex variable in python debugger, like pudb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12426106/inspect-complex-variable-in-python-debugger-like-pudb)

The short way: Highlight the variable and press backslash **\** to toggle between the "Expanded" view of a variable in the variable inspection panel.

In this case we would just highlight **self**, and press **\**, which is just the Python variable representing the instance of the class.

Alternatively, press ENTER to open the "Variable Inspection Options" menu where at the bottom you can see the "Expanded" option.